# App Inventor with Mysql and Javascript

Tags: javascript, app-inventor

A javascript issue again, I can't understand the problem. I use Appinventor to transfer a message to an html file using webviewstring. the message sent is here, starting with `1%mc`:[image]

As you can see, it jumps to the next line because everyline has an `\n` at the end.

In javascript, I try to create an array of arrays using this code:

```
var wvdata = window.AppInventor.getWebViewString().split('\n');
var urlArray = [];
for (var i in wvdata){
    urlArray.push(wvdata[i].split('%'));
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with it, since it was running fine when I splitted it with a `,`. Just because I need to use comma in some places, I changed my splitters to `%` but this doesn't work. I use script blocks like this one to assign data inside the array to items, but now it just shows the default data, as if there were nothing inside `urlArray`.

```
document.getElementById("testname0").innerHTML = urlArray[0][2];
```

Comment: I would convert the `commas` in **App Inventor** by `pipe` symbols and pass the data as 2 dimensional JavaScript array to the HTML file as in [this example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mitappinventortest/pVA3VUMN5W8/pZLttKYl3-8J), in the HTML file you then only have to convert the `pipe` symbols back to `commas`...

Comment: tried that, but when I try to pass list of lists through the webviewer, I get the first letter. the urlArray[0][0] returns me just "m" and [0][1] returns "c". I couldn't solve that out, so I did just like the first example in your page, but in a while loop. while splitting with commas, everything worked fine. Now I split them with %, it doesn't work. comma is important in my app,  I have to see and use it.